# How to strip URL parameters in .htaccess without blowing up Wordpress

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to strip extraneous parameters off a Wordpress friendly URL, such as:

```
/foo-post-name.html?sf123456=1
```

I have added the following directive to .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(?!wp-admin))(.*)$ $1? [R=301,L]
```

And that ensures that any URL except /wp-admin will strip off the URL parms.  However, I just realized I also need to exclude URLs like /?p=12345&preview=true from URL parameter strippage.

I've tried changing it to:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!wp-admin|p=))(.*)$ $1? [R=301,L]
```

...but that does not work (500 server error).  How should I modify my regex so that /?p=1234 isn't redirected?

The only parameters I need to support is 'p and preview'.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Are you using permalinks? if so what is your permalink structure?

Answer (score 1):

You can't match against query strings in the RewriteRule, but you can in a RewriteCond using *%{QUERY_STRING}*. This is kind of messy but is this what you're trying to do?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !^/wp-admin
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^p=([0-9]+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  !preview=true
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?p=%1   [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !^/wp-admin
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^p=([0-9]+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  preview=true
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?p=%1\&preview=true   [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !^/wp-admin
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  !^p=[0-9]+
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  preview=true
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?preview=true   [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !^/wp-admin
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?   [L,R=301]
```